# Are inner classes syntactic sugar of what?

Tags: java

From Java in a Nutshell

> **Inner classes are just syntactic sugar,** so locks on inner classes
>   have no effect on the enclosing class (and vice versa).

Are inner classes syntactic sugar of what? In other words, can inner classes be rewritten equivalently in terms of other more basic constructs?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. An inner class `Inner` in a class `some.pkg.Outer` is turned into a class `some.pkg.Outer$Inner`, with a reference to an instance of `Outer`. You can implement such a class by hand (although the visibility of members would not *quite* be the same).

Comment: Thanks. What does `$` mean in `some.pkg.Outer$Inner`?

Comment: It's just a symbol in the identifier, in the same way as `I`, `n`, `e` or `r` etc. You can use it where you like, but [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) recommends only using it in generated code.

Comment: In other words, inner classes are just syntactic sugar for declaring a separate top-level class.  If you have `Outer{ Inner {} }` it's basically the same thing as having two classes, `Outer{}` and `Inner {}`.

Comment: Although I certainly agree that inner classes are syntactic sugar, the rest of the quote doesn't make much sense out of context.  I have a guess as to what the second part means, but if I'm right then I don't see why that follows from the first part.

Comment: I'm guessing "lock" refers to taking a lock with the `synchronized` key word.  If you think of the two classes as two separate top-level classes, I think it's obvious that taking the lock of one has no effect on the other.

Answer (score 6):

An inner class, `Inner`, like this:

```
package some.pkg;
class Outer {
  class Inner {}
}
```

becomes a class like this when compiled:

```
package some.pkg;
class Outer$Inner {
  private final Outer this$0;

  Outer$Inner(Outer this$0) {
    this.this$0 = this$0;
  }
}
```

You can just declare this class by hand.

Well, it's *almost* like that. There are some details around providing access to members of `Inner` to instances of `Outer`; but this is broadly it.

---

Oh, this is interesting. There *is* a difference in the generated code.

If you compile the "sugared" code, the decompiled bytecode of `Outer$Inner` is:

```
  some.pkg.Outer$Inner(some.pkg.Outer);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: aload_1       
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:Lsome/pkg/Outer;
       5: aload_0       
       6: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       9: return
```

If you decompile the "desugared" version (with the `$`s), it is:

```
  some.pkg.Outer$Inner(some.pkg.Outer);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: aload_1       
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field this$0:Lsome/pkg/Outer;
       9: return
```

In other words, the `this$0` field is assigned *before* invoking the parent constructor in the first case, but *after* in the second.

The only difference I can see this making is that it allows you to pass `Outer.this` as a parameter to the parent constructor (e.g. `super(Outer.this)`; or to allow the parent constructor to invoke methods using the value of `Outer.this` (which is gross, because other fields may not have been initialized when that method is called; but it is nonetheless allowed).

So, I take it back: you can't *quite* implement the same class by hand; but the difference between the two is only important in what must be a pretty rare use case.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments inner classes are just syntactic sugar for declaring a separate top-level class.It's basically the same thing as having two classes **with the the difference** that you use them if you want to create class which is used by ONLY enclosing class (logically grouping classes that are used in one-place). In this case the reason you may want to use them (and add this syntactic sugar) from java documentation is:

- It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place.
- It increases encapsulation.
- It can lead to more readable and maintainable code.